# How to give variable values from a function to another function?

Tags: python

Im making a "game" for practice. Its a basic guess game, but i wanted to make the game only with functions. This is my problem (for ex.):

```
function 1:
   variablaA
   #some other code

function 2:
   variableB
   variableC = varibleA + variableB
   #some other code
```

I have tried too goole about objects and classes but im not sure i understand what im doing right now.

```
import random
import sys

min = 1
max = 99
guessed_number = random.randint(min, max)

class functions:
    def __init__(game, difficulty, lifes):
        game.difficulty = difficulty
        game.lifes = lifes

    def GameDiff(hardness):
        #Setting game difficulty
        print "Select difficulty : \n 1; Easy \n 2; Medium \n 3; Hard \n"
        difficulty = raw_input()
        if difficulty == "1":
            print "Its just the beginning"
            lifes = 15
        elif difficulty == "2":
            lifes = 10
        elif difficulty == "3":
            lifes = 5
        else:
            print "This isn't an option try again"
            GameDiff(hardness)

    def core(basic):
        #The core of the game
        print "I guessed a number..."
        player_number = int(raw_input("Whats the number I thinking of?"))
        constant = 1
        GameTime = 1
        while GameTime == constant:
            if player_number < guessed_number:
                print "Your number is smaller than my guessed number"
                print "Try to duplicate your number (But maybe Im wrong)"
                player_number = int(raw_input("Make your tip again\n"))

            elif player_number > guessed_number:
                print "Your number is bigger than my guessed number"
                print "Try to half your number (But maybe Im wrong)"
                player_number = int(raw_input("Make your tip again\n"))
            else:
                GameTime = 0
                print "You guessed it! Congratulations"

    def main(self):
        #The whole game only with functions
        functions.GameDiff()
        functions.core()

Function = functions()

Function.main()
```

Comment: can you please explain? what help do you need in above code?It is not clear from your description `function 1: variablaA #some other code

function 2: variableB variableC = varibleA + variableB #some other code
` as for this question you can call `function 2` from `function 1` or you can decalare `variableA` outside both function so both can access value of `variableA`

Comment: (1) you are not setting the class variables. When you set `lifes` you are only setting the variable inside the scope of the function `GameDiff`. When that function finishes running, `lifes` gets removed from memory. If you want the value of `lifes` to presist, you have to indicate to python that you are setting it as a class variable by setting `game.lifes`. (2) You will have to pass `game` as the first variable in your `GameDiff` method; otherwise it will not have access to the class variables. (3) People conventionally use `self` and not `game` to refer to the class itself.

Comment: Please be aware that when you use a class, you are approaching your problem using a class and *not* "only with functions". Please help us help you by making it clear whether you have problems about nomenclature (functions versus methods), architecture (attributes versus globals) or plainly getting the code to run.

Answer (score 0):

if you are defining function with parameters, you need to pass data(parameters) into a function when you call it

example:

```
def my_function(name):
  print("my name is " + name)

my_function("Kevin")
```

in your case you define:

```
def GameDiff(hardness):
def core(basic):
```

which are expecting parameters

and when you are calling those funcitions, you are doing that on wrong way:

```
    def main(self):
        #The whole game only with functions
        functions.GameDiff()
        functions.core()

Function = functions()
```

you need to pass parameters

example:

```
        functions.GameDiff(5)
        functions.core(1)

Function = functions(1,5)
```

NOTE: good practice will be to use **self** instead of **game**

```
    def __init__(self, difficulty, lifes):
       self.difficulty = difficulty
       self.lifes = lifes
```

> they are just two different kinds of class elements:
>
> Elements outside the **init** method are static elements; they belong
> to the class.  They're shared by all instances.
>
> Elements inside the **init** method are elements of the
> object (self); they don't belong to the class.Variables created inside **init** (and all other method functions) and prefaced with self. belong to the object instance.

Comment: Firstly i didn't wanted to use parameters. But when i wanted to run the file the error message was something about the arguments. 

It is possible to not give parameters to a function?